# What are good RPC frameworks between a Java server and C++ clients?

Tags: java, c++, rmi, protocols, rpc

I am looking for a RPC stack that can be used between a Java Server and C++ clients.

My requirements are:

1. Ease of integration (for both C++ and Java)
2. Performance, especially number of concurrent connections and response time. Payload are mostly binaries (8-100kb)

I found some like:
 http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-socket-rpc/
 http://code.google.com/p/netty-protobuf-rpc/

Are there any other good alternatives?

Comment: Are you doing anything that's complicated enough so shoving the data back and forth using simple sockets isn't an option?

Comment: I was worried about the complexity of the implementation (i.e. more code) and the difficulty to use NIO sockets (we want to have high number of connections, preferably cached). The logic we do is actually pretty simple.. Send stuff, get result, send stuff...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Thrift](http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/) might be worth investigating.

Answer (score 2):

I used to worked with protocol buffer and I was very satisfied. It's really very, very fast.
And You can easy integrate it with Java and C++.

Comment: Did you use any RPC stack on top of protobuf?

Comment: In our project we didn't use to any top layer over the ProtoBuf.
We used (I wasn't alone in the project) ProtoBuf to do RPC.